# Can't get stored procedure results with Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6

I have a stored procedure which returns a `0` or a `1` depending on whether or not a specified email address exists in my database:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [DatabaseSchema].[EmailAddressIsDuplicate] (@emailAddress nvarchar(255))
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS(
        SELECT *
        FROM [DatabaseSchema].[EmailUpdatesRegistrant]
        WHERE EmailAddress = @emailAddress
    )
        RETURN 1
    ELSE
        RETURN 0

    RETURN 0
END

GO
```

And I'm trying to derive the results of this stored procedure from an Entity Framework 6 database context:

```
using (DatabaseContext dbContext = new DatabaseContext())
{
    ObjectParameter param = new ObjectParameter("emailAddress", typeof(bool));
    var result = dbContext.EmailAddressIsDuplicate(emailAddress); 
}
```

I'm getting lots of errors.

**Error #1:** Using the code above, `var result` is always set to -1.

**Error #2:** I tried navigated to `Edit Function Import` and set the `Returns a Collection Of` to a `Boolean` scalar value. This throws the following error:

> The data reader returned by the store data provider does not have enough columns for the query requested.

**Error #3:** I went back and set the `Edit Function Import` return value to `None`. Then I tried the following code from this answer:

```
using (DatabaseContext dbContext = new DatabaseContext())
{
    var p = new SqlParameter("@emailAddress", emailAddress);
    var result = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<bool>("DatabaseSchema.EmailAddressIsDuplicate", p);
}
```

No immediate errors thrown, but I have no idea whether or not I can derive useful data from `var result`. Trying to cast `result` to `bool` throws the following error:

> Cannot convert type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbRawSqlQuery' to 'bool'

Any ideas on how I can see the results of this stored procedure (`0` or `1`)?

Comment: what is the return type of EmailAddressIsDuplicate(emailAddress); 
at the present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try adding an output parameter (`@result`) in the stored procedure signature:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [DatabaseSchema].[EmailAddressIsDuplicate]
    (@emailAddress nvarchar(255), @result bit out)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS(SELECT *
              FROM [DatabaseSchema].[EmailUpdatesRegistrant]
              WHERE EmailAddress = @emailAddress)
       SET @result = 1
    ELSE
       SET @result = 0

    RETURN @result
END
GO
```

(you'll have to re-define your EF Model Function definition accordingly)

```
using (DatabaseContext dbContext = new DatabaseContext())
{
    ObjectParameter isDuplicate = new ObjectParameter("isDuplicate", typeof(bool)); 
    var result = dbContext.EmailAddressIsDuplicate(emailAddress, isDuplicate);

    bool emailIsDuplicate = (bool)isDuplicate.Value;.    
}
```

If you want to call the stored procedure directly with an out parameter you could follow this suggestion:
[Database.SqlQuery calling stored procedure that has multiple output parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21918368/database-sqlquery-calling-stored-procedure-that-has-multiple-output-parameters)

Comment: if you are returning a integer anyway you can atleast retun the rowcount from procedure with out having an intermediate out parameter.

Comment: I Originally wrote my suggestion with a return Bit type.
@alex can try it both ways .

Comment: This ultimately helped me find my answer.  I updated the stored procedure, and used the following code: `ObjectParameter isDuplicate = new ObjectParameter("isDuplicate", typeof(bool)); var result = dbContext.EmailAddressIsDuplicate(emailAddress, isDuplicate); bool emailIsDuplicate = (bool)isDuplicate.Value;`. Using `int retParam` will throw a compile-time error.  Please update your answer with this working code and I will mark it as accepted - thanks!

Comment: Will do.  I was originally going to include the Parameter definition. Nice work implementing it. Thanks, Regards.

Answer (score 2):

**REASON** - The template builder for EF (including v6) incorrectly sets the SP up as returning an INT containing the row count rather than the return value because it incorrectly calls the wrong ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction (found in the template-generated class YourDatabaseEntities that is the child of the DBContext).

Why wrong ExecuteFunction? - The result set incorrectly says the row count of changed rows rather than the return value or output parameters because it calls a different ExecuteFunction that discards the results. The flyover intellisense hint of the ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction says "Executes a stored procedure ….; *discards any results returned from the function; and returns the number of rows affected by the execution*" rather than the usual "Executes a stored procedure …. *with the specified parameters*".

WHY -1: I believe the SET NOCOUNT ON is causing the SP to return no count result and that Microsoft's ExecuteFunction returns that as error code.

**SP FIXES** - 1) You have to comment out SET NOCOUNT ON .
2) You have to change stored procedure to do the SELECT command as last statement instead of the RETURN command.

**SOLUTION FIX** - 1) After fixing SP, delete SP from Function Imports folder and the Data Store's SP folder. 2) Reload the SP into the EDMX by using the "Update Model from Database" 3) Rebuild all of your data project where the EDMX resides. 4) Exit Visual Studio and return. 5) Rebuild overall solution.

See: [Entity Framework (Database first) has incorrect return result from stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46590413/entity-framework-database-first-has-incorrect-return-result-from-stored-proced)

Comment: Superb answer!  EF6 bug was my conclusion too but interesting to see such a thorough explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the stored procedure in C# to a value using parameters.

Resource: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8(v=vs.110).aspx

This way, the values can be stored to a variable from the `ExecuteReader`.

Add the value to model similar to adding a value to a property. The stored procedure could be called from ActionResult. Though this may require adding the stored procedure to a separate layer, that simply runs the stored procedure and adds the value to model afterwards.

Comment: I can call the stored procedure using `SqlConnection` as the link suggests, but I'm trying to do this with Entity Framework 6.

Comment: Is the SqlConnection within a separate layer from your entity framework model? After retrieving the values, from the SqlConnection and Reader, add it to a property of the model that the value belongs to.

Comment: You don't need Entity Framework to open up a `SqlConnection`.  Sure, I can just do this without Entity Framework - but the underlying problem was that Entity Framework doesn't play nicely with stored procedures.  [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39417055/3474146) answered my question.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [DatabaseSchema].[EmailAddressIsDuplicate] (@emailAddress nvarchar(255))
AS
BEGIN

        SELECT *
        FROM [DatabaseSchema].[EmailUpdatesRegistrant]
        WHERE EmailAddress = @emailAddress

    SELECT @@ROWCOUNT

END

GO


using (DatabaseContext dbContext = new DatabaseContext())
{ 
    var result = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<int32>("exec  DatabaseSchema.EmailAddressIsDuplicate {0}", emailAddress).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Anything other 0 in the return value indicates there is a match and the number indicates the number of matches

Comment: Then `var result` is of type `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbRawSqlQuery<int>`, and `result[0]` throws the error `Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbRawSqlQuery<int>'`  What do I do with `var result`?

Comment: the result is a number which indicates the number of matches found in the database.

Comment: Nope, `var result` is a `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbRawSqlQuery<int>` - not an integer.

Comment: For your purpose it can still be treated as c# integer.

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer, but the answer is not correct.  Take a look at the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery(v=vs.113).aspx) - it says: `Return Value Type: System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbRawSqlQuery<TElement>.  This means `var result` is not an integer.  You'd have to enumerate the result of the `SqlQuery` to derive the `int32`.

Comment: sorry mybad.It should be using FirstOrDefault.I just realized it is missing. I have changed my answer to reflect the same.It should work now.