# Fetch stored procedure value

Tags: sql, asp.net, stored-procedures

I have a table `RhSeq` which contains the following columns:

```
ScoTable (PK, varchar(20),not NULL)
ScoColonne (PK, varchar(50), not NULL)
ScoSequence (int, not NULL)
ScoDescription (varchar(100), not NULL)
```

I have a stored procedure which, given `ScoTable` and `ScoColonne`, increments `ScoSequence` and returns the incremented `ScoSequence` value:

EDITED - Here's the full stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_RhSeqNextVal]
@table VARCHAR (20), @colonne VARCHAR (30), @sequence_id INT OUTPUT
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON  
SET @sequence_id = -1

DECLARE @transaction AS BIT
    SET @transaction = 0;

IF 0 = @@TRANCOUNT
BEGIN
   BEGIN TRAN
   SET @transaction = 1;  
END

UPDATE dbo.RhSeq
   SET ScoSequence = CASE WHEN Right(@colonne,1) = '-' THEN
           ScoSequence - 1
       ELSE
           ScoSequence + 1
       END
 WHERE ScoTable = @table
   AND ScoColonne = @colonne

SELECT @sequence_id = ScoSequence 
  FROM dbo.RhSeq 
 WHERE ScoTable = @table
   AND ScoColonne = @colonne

 IF 1 = @transaction
 BEGIN
     COMMIT TRAN
 END
```

In Visual Studio, if I right click on the stored procedure (in Server Explorer) and choose 'Execute', I enter values for `ScoTable` and `ScoColonne` and set `sequence_id` to null and it executes fine, returning the new incremented `sequence_id` value. So no problem with the stored procedure.

The problem I have is when I try to get the returned `sequence_id` inside my code.

```
SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@ScoTable", "MyTable");
SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter("@ScoColonne", "MyColumn");
SqlParameter param3 = new SqlParameter("@sequence_id", DBNull.Value);

var numeroSequence = db.Database.SqlQuery<RhSeq>("usp_RhSeqNextVal @ScoTable,@ScoColonne, @sequence_id", param1, param2,param3).ToList();
```

I get an error

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: A member of the type, 'ScoTable', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name

From my understanding, the error comes from `RhSeq`, since the stored procedure returns only `sequence_id`, which is an `int`, it cannot create a `RhSeq` object with it. I try to cast the result to an `int`, but it's still not working.

How can I store the `sequence_id` returned by the stored procedure into my var `numeroSequence`?

Comment: Please post your stored procedure complete definition at least the input parameter definition and final output

Comment: Your stored procedure not return anything or you did not post it complete code

Comment: Updated with complete SP

Comment: Found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21918368/database-sqlquery-calling-stored-procedure-that-has-multiple-output-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue in LinqToSQL. Selecting @sequence_id in the procedure after setting it did the job:

In your SP after:

```
SELECT @sequence_id = ScoSequence 
FROM dbo.RhSeq
WHERE ScoTable = @table
AND ScoColonne = @colonne
```

Add:

```
SELECT @sequence_id
```

And then of course:

```
db.Database.SqlQuery<int>...
```