# EF 6 : how to call a stored procedure with multiple output params

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I have a .NET 4.8 app that is calling a SQL Server stored procedure using `SqlQuery` (inside a `DbContext`). Most of the stored procedures take a couple of input parameters and return a number of rows, with a single output parameter giving the number of rows returned. These work fine.

I have one stored procedure that takes a single input, returns no rows, but has three output parameters. When I call this, I get no data returned and the output parameters appear to be unset (null).

```
PROCEDURE GetBob 
    @InVal INT, 
    @OutVal1 INT OUTPUT, 
    @OutVal2 NVARCHAR(30) OUTPUT, 
    @OutRows INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @OutVal1 = 1
    SELECT @OutVal2 = "bob"
    SELECT @OutRows = 1
END
```

When I execute this in SQL Server, I get 1, bob and 1 respectively.

```
SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter() {
    Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input,
    ParameterName = "@InVal",
    SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int,
    Value = 1
};

SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter() {
    Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output,
    ParameterName = "@OutVal1",
    SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int,
};
            
// etc. for the last two params.
```

And my call is defined as follows:

```
var x = Database.SqlQuery<ab>("GetBob @InVal, @OutVal1, @OutVal2, @OutRows", param1, param2, param3, param4).ToList();
```

For this example, ab is a class that contains a property for each output parameter.

Does anyone have any ideas why it is not picking up the output parameters. I would expect x to be empty as no actual rows are returned, but the output parameters should be populated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Database.SqlQuery calling stored procedure that has multiple output parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21918368/database-sqlquery-calling-stored-procedure-that-has-multiple-output-parameters)

Comment: Thanks, I say that yesterday, however, having a re-read, I noticed the OUT keyword after the out parameters.  This does not appear to be needed if there is just ONE out parameter, which is why I was seeing the other queries work, but IS required if there is more than one out param.  I changed my code above to OutVal1 OUT, OutVal2 OUT, OutRows OUT  and I am now getting values returned. Will mark your reply as answer as soon as I can figure out how.